# Unity quality settings reset on load level

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm adding an game options screen using Unity. This includes settings such as Antialiasing and Anistropic Filtering.

```
QualitySettings.antiAliasing = level;
// level = 0,2,4 or 8
```

I can see that these are being applied as expected when on the main menu, but as soon as I change scene using `Application.LoadLevel` they all reset to 0. It also comes up in this state on first load.

[image: Quality Settings reset to 0]

I'm running the application under the default "Fantastic" quality settings, and have checked that the default AA is set to 8x, so I'm not quite sure why it would reset to 0 anyway! I'm not 100% sure at this initial state if the AA is actually off, or the value returned is wrong.

---

- How do I get these settings to stick?
- Is the problem that `QualitySettings` simply doesn't return the correct current value?
- Do I need to store them in a game settings static class, and keep reapplying them?
- Do I need to save and reload them myself, or can the quality settings system take care of this?

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm now pretty sure that actually QualitySettings is only used for SETTING quality options, not getting them. If this is the case I'm not sure why they're all available as read/write fields.

To solve the problem I'm planning on creating a quality settings file, pulling that into a static class when the game loads, applying them, then make the options page reflect those values.

I'll leave this open in case anyone has another way of getting at the current built in Quality Settings values.

Comment: You could also consider putting your qualitysettings into an empty game object and then calling DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject); so that the object persist over the duration the application is running. Not certain why the quality settings are resetting when you load a new scene though.